# Terraform and complex variables

Tags: terraform, hcloud

I am using the "Hetzner" provider with Terraform.
My plan is to have something like this in fx `.auto.tfvars` :

```
fw_openings = [
   {
      port = "22",
      protocol = "tcp",
      subnet = "100.100.100.100/32"
   },
   {
      port = "80",
      protocol = "tcp",
      subnet = "0.0.0.0/0"
   }
]
```

Based on the `fw_openings` I would like to generate something like this:

```
resource "hcloud_firewall" "firewall" {
   rule {
      direction = "in"
      protocol = "tcp"
      port = "22"
      source_ips = [
         "100.100.100.100/32"
      ]
   }
   rule {
      direction = "in"
      protocol = "tcp"
      port = "80"
      source_ips = [
         "0.0.0.0/0"
      ]
   }
}
```

I'm sure it's possible (since it seems very trivial). But I seem to keep tripping over the looping options with Terraform.
What would be the proper solution?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do? –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [dynamic blocks](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks):

```
resource "hcloud_firewall" "firewall" {
   dynamic "rule" {
   
      for_each = var.fw_openings
   
      content {
            direction = "in"
            protocol = rule.value.protocol
            port = rule.value.port
            source_ips = [
                rule.value.subnet
            ]
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: @ZiGGi No problem. If the answer helped, its [acceptance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86979) would be appreciated.

Comment: I think I got carried away and completely forgot to respond. I'm sorry for that! Especially since it worked like a charm